# Creating groups of specified length from pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas noob, can't for the life of me figure out how to implement as a one-liner without using a python function (as I am trying to learn pandas and feel like it could handle this). Hints?

I have a dataframe of conversational utterances, and I'd like create groups of utterances where the group size is fed in from a list.

```
#utterance column in list form
utterance_list = ['this', 'is', 'not', 'working']

df = pd.DataFrame({'utterances': utterance_list})

#list of desired group sizes
sizes = [1, 0, 3]

{insert missing function here}

desired output = ['this', '', 'is not working']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses only `pandas` and `numpy`.

Since `pandas` stores data in `numpy` arrays, there's no reason you should avoid using `numpy` functionality.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

A = np.array(['this', 'is', 'not', 'working'])
sizes = np.array([1, 0, 3])

df = pd.DataFrame({'utterances': utterance_list})

df['utterances'] = np.split(A, sizes.cumsum())

print(df)

#            utterances
# 0              [this]
# 1                  []
# 2  [is, not, working]
# 3                  []
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "no Python function" - but here is one way.

```
import numpy as np

lst = ['this', 'is', 'not', 'working']
sizes = [1, 0, 3]

idx1 = np.array([0] + sizes).cumsum()[:-1]
idx2 = idx1 + np.array(sizes)

print(idx1, idx2)
# [0 1 1] [1 1 4]

res = [lst[i:j] for i, j in zip(idx1, idx2)]

print(res)
# [['this'], [], ['is', 'not', 'working']]
```

If you really need a one-liner:

```
res = [lst[i:i+j] for i, j in zip(np.array([0] + sizes).cumsum()[:-1], np.array(sizes))]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is not unhelpful, but I was hoping to implement using Pandas exclusively. Can this not be implemented somehow with groupby or something?

Comment: @xoihiox, Not sure - you can wait for another answer.